# Pycharm virtualenv stops working suddenly as contextlib module goes missing

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, virtual-environment

Pycharm (**Win10**) stopped running suddenly with following error

```
..\env\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 64065 --file start_file.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 7, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
ImportError: No module named 'contextlib'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to import contextlib within virtual env but:

```
...\venv>Scripts\activate

(venv) ...\venv>pip install contextlib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement contextlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for contextlib
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How an I fix this?

I can see contextlib in Lib module within win explorer:

[image: contextlib in Lib module within win explorer]

I upgraded pip and yet

```
venv>pip install contextlib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement contextlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for contextlib

venv>pip install 'contextlib==3.8'
ERROR: Invalid requirement: "'contextlib==3.8'"
```

Is there any version I should specify for contextlib while importing?

Comment: What python version is your venv? From the screenshot it seems like you checked in you local python installation which is different from venv.

Comment: Seems venv is on correct version -- venv>python --version
Python 3.8.0

Comment: Did you update Python recently? If yes then there are lots of things that could go wrong. Try deleting your venv and creating a new one

Comment: venv version is 3.8 - python is also 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @hurlenko.

Not sure what the issue was but following solved it:

```
- Install new venv using desired Python executable
- Try and install the requirements within custom requirements file
- Use the venv and create debug config in Pycharm
- Run the new config within Pycharm
- Got dependency errors - install dependency (using Pycharm as it is way easier)
- Got new dependency errors due to installation in previous step - installed the newly failing dependencies
- Repeat the above step until all dependencies are resolved
```

After that I was able to run without issues.